# Loop through json with timeout variabe, javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a bit of a problem making an intro to my web-based game. It is basically a small scene where two people talk to eachother using speech bubbles.
I have decided to go with json and ES6 JavaScript.

My json looks like this:

```
const script_scene1 = [
    {
        speaker: 'Ted',
        timer: 3000,
        emote: 'normal',
        quote: ''
    },
    {
        speaker: 'Ted',
        timer: 3000,
        emote: 'normal',
        quote: 'Bill, Bill? Where are you?'
    },
    {
        speaker: 'Bill',
        timer: 4000,
        emote: false,
        quote: 'Oh, Ted, I am lost. I think someone kidnapped me.'
    },
    {
        speaker: 'Ted',
        timer: 3000,
        emote: 'normal',
        quote: 'How did they kidnap you?'
    }
];
```

My JS looks like this:

```
function playIntro() {
    let intro = document.getElementById("SceneOne");
    intro.style.display= "block";
    playScene(1, intro);
};

function playScene(scene) {
    let currentScript = getScript(scene);

    [].forEach.call(currentScript, function(subScript) {
            playSubScene(subScript);
    });
};

function playSubScene(script) {
    let speaker = script.speaker;
    let emote = script.emote;
    let quote = script.quote;

    let bubbles = document.querySelectorAll("speech");
    [].forEach.call(bubbles, function(bubble) {
        bubble.style.display = "none";
    });

    let bubble = document.getElementById(speaker);
    bubble.style.display = "block";
    bubble.innerHTML = quote;
};
```

And my HTML like this:

```
<section class="scene1" id="SceneOne">
    <button class="close-button" id="CloseButton">X</button>
    <div class="emoter1">
        <img src="images/ted.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="emoter2">
        <img src="images/bill.png" />
    </div>
    <article class="bubble pos1" id="Ted"></article>
    <article class="bubble pos2" id="Bill"></article>
    <article class="bubble pos3" id="RussetFive"></article>
    <article class="bubble pos4" id="DinkyPinky"></article>
</section>
```

Now, what I want to do is to loop through the dialouge in my script so that each character speaks in turn and their text is shown the given amount of seconds (the timer value).

I have tested setTimeout, but to no avail. I have tried to understand how that works with callbacks, but I have not gotten that to work. I have also looked into promises, but I don't really see how to get that to work within a loop.

It seemed so simple when I had the idea how to do this, but now I've been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered I thought I'd post my own solution even though it might not be the most beautiful one.

First off, I was wrong to say that I was working with a json object, it is in fact a javascript object.

The way I solved it was to create a timer for each object where the time from the previous objects was added on to it. That is to say, each line of dialogue gets its own timer.

```
function playScene(scene) {
    let currentScript = getScript(scene);
    let currentTimer = 0;

    [].forEach.call(currentScript, function(element) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            playSubScene(element);
        }, currentTimer);
        currentTimer = currentTimer + element.timer;
    });
};
```